# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception at runtime

Tags: java

My code compiles, but I get this error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at staffstore.writestaff(staffstore.java:16)
at addStaffGUI$2.actionPerformed(addStaffGUI.java:89)
```

This is the part of code I believe to be causing the problem:

```
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setBounds(145,470,100,20);
    panel2.add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stfname =(stfnametb.getText());
            stlname =(stlnametb.getText());
            staddress2 =(staddresstb.getText());
            stphone2 =(stphonetb.getText());

            try {
                staffstore.writestaff();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            third.dispose();

          }
        });
```

This is line 9-19 of StaffStore.java

```
    String[] stlist = new String[5];
  /*stlist[0] = addStudentGUI.fname;
  stlist[1] = addStudentGUI.lname;
  stlist[2] = addStudentGUI.sgrade;
  stlist[3] = addStudentGUI.saddress;
  stlist[4] = addStudentGUI.sphone;*/ 

  stlist[5] = addStaffGUI.stfname;
  stlist[6] = addStaffGUI.stlname;
  stlist[7] = addStaffGUI.staddress2;
  stlist[8] = addStaffGUI.stphone2;
```

Comment: Where's the code for line 16 of staffstore.java? This is where your problem is per the exception message: `at staffstore.writestaff(staffstore.java:16)`. It's stating that an array or collection index value is 5 when the array or collection doesn't hold 5 items.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a runtime exception anyway, so you wouldn't encounter it while compiling.

Comment: I included line 16 of staffstore.java just now

Comment: Of course it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

An array of size *n* can only have an index position up to size *n-1*.  The highest such index for an array of size 5 is 4.

That said, these four declarations are illegal:

```
stlist[5] = addStaffGUI.stfname;
stlist[6] = addStaffGUI.stlname;
stlist[7] = addStaffGUI.staddress2;
stlist[8] = addStaffGUI.stphone2;
```

I'm not entirely sure what your motiviation is here, but you need to get those four values in bounds.

```
stlist[0] = addStaffGUI.stfname;
stlist[1] = addStaffGUI.stlname;
stlist[2] = addStaffGUI.staddress2;
stlist[3] = addStaffGUI.stphone2;
```

Since you've also got other values commented out, it could be a simple matter of increasing the size of your array, too:

```
String[] stlist = new String[9];
```

...but then you have to be sure that you don't try to invoke any methods on any of the first five entries in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an array that holds 5 items and you're trying to get the value in the 6th spot. Don't do that.

```
String[] stlist = new String[5];
stlist[5] = addStaffGUI.stfname;
```

Also you're trying to hold different information in a single array, something that is a poor and brittle design. Instead create an array or better, an ArrayList of Staff items.

```
// declared as a field of the class:
private List<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList<>();

// elsewhere
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String stfname = stfnametb.getText();
        String stlname = stlnametb.getText();
        String staddress2 = staddresstb.getText();
        String stphone2 = stphonetb.getText();

        // use information obtained to create a Staff object
        Staff staff = new Staff(stfname, stlname, staddress2, stphone2);

        // maybe done here, maybe in staffStore
        staffList.add(staff);

        try {
            // pass the Staff object into this method
            staffstore.writestaff(staff);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        third.dispose();
    }
});
```

The most important lessons to gain from this experience are:

- Just because code compiles does not mean that it is *correct*.
- The Exception stacktrace often contains key information that will tell you exactly what is wrong and where. Read it critically and look carefully at the lines it indicates to you.